# Equivalence of simple random sampling with- and without- replacement

Tags: sampling

We know that in simple random sampling without replacement the probability of drawing n units from a population of N units(where ordering is considered) is 1/(N)n or 1/(N n) (where ordering is not considered).

How is this equivalent to drawing units independently one by one and with replacement where each unit has probability of selection 1/N at each draw, until n distinct units are drawn and then discarding the repeated units?